# Parse IPAddress from text file (loaded into string)

Tags: c#, string, server, ip, ip-address

I'm trying to get my client app to connect to a server on a remote machine operating on my local network without knowing the server's IP Address to begin with.

Ideally I'd like the client to connect automatically, but since I've been having trouble getting that to work properly, I thought for now I'd have the user manually input their server's IP Address into the client.

I've saved the inputted IP address to a file and loaded it into a string:

```
string ServerIP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg");
```

but I'm not sure how to set that string as the IPEndPoint:

```
private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Insert ServerIP string here"), 8888);
```

I've unsuccessfully tried using `ipString`, `IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP, 8888);`, `IPAddress.Parse(string ServerIP, 8888);` and multiple other combinations, I still can't figure out the proper syntax for this method, and my Google-fu has failed me on this one.

---

**EDIT:** With this implementation I don't get any errors until I try to debug, and I get:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null." on `Client.Connect(serverEndPoint);`

```
    private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;
    private TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();

    public Client()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
        string ServerIP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg");
        serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPAddress.Parse` only takes one argument, I believe you meant to put the port in the `IPEndPoint` constructor and not the `Parse` method.

```
private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, and I get the error: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property`

Comment: Ah I missed the `private`. In this case, declare the field like: `private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint`. Then, after you read the file, add `serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);` (Basically split the declaration and where it is set)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused on what you mean there, do you mean:         `private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;` then
        `string ServerIP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg");` then
        `private serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);`? That doesn't work, so I'm sure you mean something different than that.

Comment: Put `private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;` in your class, but not in a method. Put the two other lines inside of the method. Also remove private on the last line.

Comment: I've updated my question, I tried implementing what you've described, but I must have done something wrong, because I'm getting `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll`

Comment: You just need to rearrange your code. You are trying to connect to an endpoint that is null, because you haven't set it. Move `Client.Connect(serverEndPoint);` to the bottom of the method.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I was trying to connect before I specified the endpoint EDIT: haha, we must have noticed that at the same time